# Is it legal to put competitor name in commercials in USA?

Tags: united-states, advertisements, is-x-legal

I saw Google Ad showing "Wikibuy Beating Amazon" on website.

Website is US Based & also I am using USA Net Connection.

[image]

Is it legal to put competitor name in commercials in USA?

Comment: Yes, it is legal.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? Are you thinking about a trademark issue? An unfair competition issue? It's really hard to answer a question this abstract. Do you mean is there some law that prohibits any mention of any competitor at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfectly legitimate and legal use of a trade mark. However, as with all advertising, the claims must be truthful. If they aren't, then in addition to any state sanctions for untruthful advertising you expose yourself to a defamation suit from the competitor you defamed.

Often, such comparative advertising is actually between trade marks owned by the same company. It eliminates the risk of being sued and gives exposure to both brands in the same add.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is legal. Similar to election time when opposite parties blatantly call out the other side for their faults and wrongdoings.

Answer (score -1):

If you already see it multiple times obviously it's legal....as long as it does not constitute as blaspheme or defamation
as long as the information provided in the commercial is neutral and objective, not wilful attack ad hominem or similar things, it will be fine. :D

Comment: Being done more than once certainly does not mean obvious legality, advertising in particular.

Comment: I guess school shootings must be legal. I have seen plenty of ads that are clearly illegal, such as "make thousands of dollars a month with Google", which I'm sure aren't authorized by Google.